# How to get absolute path for directory in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have created a directory in hadoop and copied a file to that directory.

[image: I have created a file alb_upc_retailer_sku_attr_1.txt under prvys dir]

[image]

Now i want to create external hive table which will refer the above created file.

Is there way we can find out the root `dir`, under which `prvys` `dir` was created.

Answer (score 3):

By default, `hadoop fs -ls` will look at `/user/$(whoami)`

If you `echo` that path, then `-ls` it, you should find the `prvys` directory. For example, `hdfs:///user/liftadmin/`

If you're using Kerberos, then the user directory depends on the ticket you've initialized the session with